# MediaElement.js HTML5 Player skin

Tags: html, mediaelement.js, skin

i have a skin problem with MediaElement.js HTML5 Player it is on : http://bjkscout.com/forzahaber/oudio-deneme.html this link. I dont know how it happens. please hep me.

Comment: Please go <del>see a dermatologist</del> <ins>read [ask]</ins>.

Answer (score 1):

I had to add some code to my .htaccess file in order to get them to render in the player again. Hopefully this helps someone else.

```css
AddType image/svg+xml svg svgz
AddEncoding gzip svgz
```